# How to check what packages are installed on a RHEL5 system?

Tags: packages, yum, rhel-5

A command that can be run by an unprivileged user is preferred.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Long ago I would have just used

```
$ rpm -qa
```

and possibly piped it through more. Looks like is still works.

Answer (score 12):

dmckee's answer works perfectly well.

```
$ yum list installed
```

also works. No special privileges required.

Answer (score 4):

```
rpm -qa --last >~/RPMS_by_Install_Date
```

this will also give you a list of when they were installed as well ... the file will be made in your home dir.